# Regex - Get Text/Numbers Only and Extra

Tags: javascript, regex

I have some strings I need to apply regex to reformat them.

Here are some examples:

`Tree Log & Fire (TLF)`

`Leaves`

`River Moon (RM)`

The capitalization, spacing, formatting is all exactly how a string may appear.

My goal is for them to be transformed into the following:

`tree-log-fire`

`leaves`

`river-moon`

As you may notice, the `&` is gone, and any string that had `(xx)` at the end had that discarded.

I'm using JavaScript `.replace()` and tried to throw in a `match()` but it doesn't work.

Example code:

```
let newString = oldString
    .match(/[^]+(?=\s\()/)
    .replace(/[^A-Z0-9]+/ig, '-')
```

Theoretically, that would work, but I can't seem to chain the .replace to the .match. Also, I would prefer one line of Regex. I have been trying combinations, but I know someone may be a little more clever than I with regular expressions!

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You cant chain `replace` onto `match`. `match` returns an array while `replace` operates on a string

Comment: Thank you, that's helpful to know!

Comment: Try `s.split(/[^A-Za-z()]+|\([^()]*\)/).filter(Boolean).map(function (x) { return x.toLowerCase(); }).join("-")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) returns an array, if there was a match. Thus to get the matched group you have to use `[0]` on the result of `.match()` before calling `.replace()`.

```js
go('Tree Log & Fire (TLF)');
go('Leaves');
go('River Moon (RM)');


function go(oldString) {
    var newString = oldString
        .match(/[^]+(?=(\s\())|.+/)[0] // <-- added [0] to get the 1st group's result str
        .replace(/[^A-Z0-9]+/ig, '-')
        .toLowerCase();

    console.log(newString);
}
```

Notice I added `|.+` to handle the `Leaves` case (where there's no `()`). Ah, and added `.toLowerCase()` as well.

Comment: Thanks @acdcjunior, I was missing that extra regex and the `[0]`! It's now doing as it should!

Answer (score 0):

This is prob not the most efficient way, but...

```js
let str= "Tree Log & Fire (TLF)";

str= str.replace(/\([^()]*\)/,'')
    .replace(/[^A-Z0-9]+/ig, '-').replace(/\-$/, "").toLowerCase();

console.log(str);
```